# DryIoc - Register Single for an existing object already created

Tags: inversion-of-control, dryioc

Is it possible to achieve something like this;

```
var myObjectInstance = new MyObject(); // We have an instance of a class.

Container.Register< IMyObject, MyObject >(Reuse.Singleton, myObjectInstance); // For example register it 

var myObjectInstance2 = Container.Resolve< IMyObject>(); // Then resolve it
```

Right now they should be equal `myObjectInstance = myObjectInstance`2

Can we do it? I didn't get success.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Like this:

```
var myObjectInstance = new MyObject();

Container.UseInstance<IMyObject>(myObjectInstance);

var myObjectInstance2 = Container.Resolve<IMyObject>();
Debug.Assert(myObjectInstance == myObjectInstance2);
```

Here is the [docs](https://bitbucket.org/dadhi/dryioc/wiki/RegisterResolve#markdown-header-useinstance).

Comment: Thank you man. What can i say, i should check the docs before write :) and your ioc container is the best i think.